# понятие O(), как посчитать время поиска?

Tags: сложность

время обработки бинарного поиска равняется O(log n).
Верно ли я понимаю то что O(log n)= O(log2 n)?

Comment: Основание логарифма неважно

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5

Comment: То есть, если в задание просят посчитать время, можно лишь написать O(log n). И все? Никаких числовых значений,

Comment: @arman если Вас просят посчитать реальное время, это одно. Если асимптотическую оценку, то O нотации должно быть достаточно. Вообще, задание надо уточнять у того, кто его задал :)

Comment: А как считать реальное время?

Comment: Реальное время на каком железе ? С каким объемом данных. Если все данные влезают в ОЗУ это одно, а если не влезают и надо обращаться к диску это совсем другое. И боюсь посчитать реальное время можно только реализовав алгоритм и проведя тест. Учесть на бумаге все нюансы невозможно. (такие как: тактовая частота процессора, количество тактов на ту или иную операцию в данном, конкретном процессоре, скорость кеша, скорость ОЗУ, распараллеливание команд процессором (выполнение на тех же тактах), подстраивание тактовой частоты под нагрузку, температура воздуха около процессора

Comment: ок, спасибо юольшое